# PHP Cookie Set when <parameter> NULL and "isset(<parameter>)" used

Tags: php, cookies

My Code is

```
<html><body>
<form method="POST" action="#">
<input type="text" name="myin">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['myin']))
{
    setcookie("Cookie","MyCookieIsThis",);
    echo $_POST['myin'];
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo $_COOKIE['Cookie'];
}
?>
```

Now, when I open the link in fresh (incognito) browser tab and keep the 'myin' parameter NULL and Submit, I don't get the Cookie output.

The 2nd time I submit the parameter NULL, I get the Cookie echo-ed.

What is the problem with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because after submit the `$_POST['myin']` is set but the content of the variable is empty string (`""`).

You can debug the code with the `var_dump($_POST);` before the if-line.